# indirect cell address of specific worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working with CELL("address") function within INDIRECT to allow multiple cells as a searchable drop downlinst, and all is working fine, Problem is, CELL("address") function use whole Workbook cells, (where ever I type no matter which Sheet I am working.
I want to use specific sheet cell address, so when ever I work on other sheets this list should not update every time. Plz help

Comment: Can you show some specific code or formulas you're using?

Comment: but I want Cell Function only get values when ever I type in Sheet2 column3

Comment: Add the full address to the `CELL` function.  `Cell("address")` will refer to the cell containing that function.

Comment: can you please share full function text (example )